# UWP Inherit from Control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

For example I have a `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SMPlayer.ScrollingTextBlock">
    <ScrollViewer
        x:Name="TextScrollViewer"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        PointerEntered="TextScrollViewer_PointerEntered"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NormalTextBlock" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="PointerOverTextBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

I want this `UserControl` still to be treated as a normal `TextBlock`. For example `<ScrollingTextBlock Text="Something"/>`. It is just a `TextBlock` with more functionalities, or in other words, another control that inherits from `TextBlock`. Because there are a lot of properties, I don't want to do this manually by adding `DependencyProperty` and do things like `public string Text { get; set; }`. It is just too much work.

How can I achieve that? I think this question might have been asked but I am not sure how to properly paraphrase it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your control to "be treated as a normal `TextBlock`", then you don't have any other choice than inheriting from `TextBlock`. This is what inheritance is for.

Otherwise you indeed have to add properties to your `UserControl` and bind them by yourself, even though this is a lot of work this is due to the poor flexibility of the `UserControl`. You cannot have a `Text` property on an object unless it inherits from a `TextBlock` or you add it yourself.

Alternatively you can use templating to re-template a `ContentControl` like this:

```cs
public class ScrollingContent : ContentControl { }
```

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:ScrollingContent">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ScrollingContent">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        x:Name="TextScrollViewer"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="NormalTextBlock" />
                            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:ScrollingContent>
        <TextBlock Text="Whatever control I want" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
    </local:ScrollingContent>
</Grid>
```

But then again, your control is not really a `TextBlock`.

Comment: This is just an example of what I want. It doesn't really matter if it is a `TextBlock`. I just want it to be treated like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement `<ScrollingTextBlock Text="Something"/>` in UserControl, you still need to add DependencyProperty to achieve it.